# Make fixed height of an video elment

Tags: css

I have a certain problem that I came across I need to make a video element with fixed height as well I have a `canvas` element that is positioned on top of the video element which represents a rectangle that is drawn across the object.

When I use `object-fit` with `max-height: 60vh`, the `canvas` element as well gets shrunk to `60vh` but instead, it should be `100% height`

```css
.display-cover {
  position: relative;
}

#video {
  min-width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  max-height: 60vh;
}

#camera-feedback {
  position: absolute;
  top: -30px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="display-cover">
  <canvas id="camera-feedback"></canvas>
  <div class="video-cover">
    <video id="video" autoplay playsinline>
      Your browser does not support the video tag.
    </video>
  </div>
</div>
```

Image example ( yellow rectangle should cover all document), when height of the video is `100%` it works fine

[image]

Comment: The height of `.display-cover` is set by it's child elements (In this case `#video` is the only element with height), and `#camera-feedback` is 100% of `.display-cover`'s height. If you want the canvas to have a set height you need to either set it on the canvas or on `.display-cover`.

Comment: I suggest [edit]ing your code to add borders and/or backgrounds so that it demonstrates the issue.

Comment: @DBS already tried to set `height` of `canvas` and `display-cover` it didn't work i updated my question with image example

Comment: could you post an example?